# Rotativa RazorPDF "trava" no IIS

Tags: c#, pdf, rotativa

Amigos, utilizo o Visual Studio C# 2015. Em um projeto MVC estou utilizando também o Rotativa RazorPDF para criar PDF a partir de páginas HTML. Quando testo a aplicação em ambiente de desenvolvimento (localhost dentro do Visual Studio) a mesma funciona 100% das vezes. Porém, ao instalar no IIS muitas das vezes a página fica "travada" e o aplicativo "wkhtmltopdf.exe" fica parado na memória. Algum dos amigos já passou por um problema assim?

Atenciosamente,

Leonardo Cruz

Comment: Pergunta ampla, evite perguntas como **"alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema?"**. Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking para aprender como fazer uma boa pergunta

Comment: Amigos, problema resolvido!  O executável baixado através da instalação do pacote no Nuget (arquivo "wkhtmltopdf.exe") veio corrompido ou com algum problema. Baixei a versão mais atual no site https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ e coloquei na pasta "/rotativa" da aplicação no ISS para resolver o problema. 

Amigo @RORSCHACH, o fato de ter colocado a pergunta "Algum dos amigos..." no final do texto não faz com que a dúvida seja ampla. Na verdade o questionamento foi bem específico e a resposta, conforme coloquei acima, também.
Abraço à todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigos, problema resolvido!

O executável baixado através da instalação do pacote no Nuget (arquivo "wkhtmltopdf.exe") veio corrompido ou com algum problema.

Para resolver o problema, baixei a versão mais atual no site wkhtmltopdf.org e coloquei na pasta "/rotativa" da aplicação no ISS para resolver o problema.

Outra coisa que se deve olhar é a versão do sistema operacional, embora no meu caso não fosse esse o caso. No referido site existem versões 32 e 64bits.

Abraços!